# Proof that $1/3(\vec{x}+\vec{y}+\vec{z})$ lies on each median of a triangle

Tags: vectors

I have already proven that the medians of a triangle intersect each other at 2/3 from each vertex.

Now I want to show that $$\vec{v}=1/3(\vec{x}+\vec{y}+\vec{z}) $$ where each vectors are three dimensional and real.

First I wanted to know if you would consider my attempt to proof this as correct (I am not sure If it is a GENERAL proof):
First I put one vertic at the origin which I can always so. I call $\vec{OM}$ the vector from the origin to the point where the medians intersect and the other vertices are OB and OC:
$$\vec{OM}=2/3(\vec{OB}+1/2\vec{CB})= 2/3(\vec{OB}+1/2(\vec{OB}-\vec{OC}))=2/3(1/2\vec{OC}+1/2\vec{OB})=1/3(\vec{OC}+\vec{OB})$$
So this shows now that $\vec{OM}$ and $\vec{v}$ are the same with one vertex at the origin.

In my exercise the question is also that I should show that $\vec{v}$ point to every median and therefore to the intersection of the medians and I am not really able to show that. I made several attempts trying to show that $\vec{v}$ is some real multiple of the meridian vectors but I could not figure out.

Comment: If you have already shown that medians intersect each another in the ratio $2:1$ then the position vector of the centroid is $\frac{z + 2 \frac{x+y}{2}}{2+1} = \frac{x+y+z}{3}$.

Comment: Ok but why, can you explain how you got the term on the left hand side?

Comment: You can check it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_formula

Comment: Thank you. And can you tell me what do you think of my calculation?